# How do I use a button to update the order of a filtered category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails, but slowly making progress. I can't quite wrap my head around how to achieve my next task.

I have a controller (IdeasController) with an index that looks like this:

```
def index

 if params[:round].blank? && params[:challenge].blank?
   @ideas = Idea.all.order(params[:sort])
 # @ideas = Idea.all.order(created_at: :desc, cached_votes_up: :desc)
 end

 if params[:round].present?
  @round_id = Round.find_by(name: params[:round]).id
  @ideas = Idea.where(round_id: @round_id).order("created_at DESC")
 end

 if params[:challenge].present?
   @challenge_id = Challenge.find_by(name: params[:challenge]).id
   @ideas = Idea.where(challenge_id: @challenge_id).order("created_at DESC")
 end

end
```

I am updating the view and filtering by category with the above :round and :challenge with the code below in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "All", ideas_path %>
<% Round.all.each do |round| %>
  <%= link_to round.name, ideas_path(round: round.name) %>
<% end %>
<% Challenge.all.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= link_to challenge.name, ideas_path(challenge: challenge.name) %>
<% end %>
```

Now, my problem is that I want to create a button that orders by created_at DESC or ASC. I want the button to essentially be a toggle. I also want another button to order by cached_weighted_average DESC or ASC. This is from acts_as_votable so I can sort by vote counts.

The problem I am running into is that I can create a link or button that orders by created_at or cached_weighted_average, but it replaces all of the URL that was previously filtered by :round or :challenge. For example, if a user clicks "Round 1" and sees all ideas marked for "Round 1" and then they click the link to order by cached_weighted_average, the URL replaces:

```
/ideas?round=Round+1
```

With this:

```
/ideas?sort=cached_weighted_average+ASC
```

What I want is:

```
/ideas?round=Round+1&?sort=cached_weighted_average+ASC
```

I know this is a very new question, but everything I have tried has failed so far. It feels like I am missing something very easy. What I noticed I can do easily is inside the controller I can do something like:

```
if params[:round].present?
  @round_id = Round.find_by(name: params[:round]).id
  @ideas = Idea.where(round_id: @round_id).order("cached_weighted_average DESC")
end
```

Which is perfect. This button just needs to switch between cached_weighted_average DESC and created_at DESC.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you can pass multiple parameters, including the existing parameters. it should also be part of one conditional instead of separate ones.

Comment: Do you have an example of this I could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

passing multiple parameters is one way to handle:

```
 <%= link_to object.name, object_path(first: something, second: something_else) %>
```

then alter your conditionals to contemplate presence of multiple params.

to differentiate between round and challenge when attempting to allow the user to choose how they'd like to sort you could use the same name and then pass it different values.

something like:

```
 params["round_or_challenge"]
```

this would change your conditional to something like:

```
 if params["round_or_challenge"] == "round" && params["asc_or_desc"] == "asc"
   # query
 elsif params["round_or_challenge"] == "challenge"
   # query 
 end
```

or whatever. it's basically the same...just pass the values you need. you can also pass the existing parameters from the view the same way you access them in the controller.

Comment: How would I pass multiple params when I have 4 different links? I have 2 links for round and challenge and then I have a link for created_at and cached_votes_total.

Comment: I don't understand this question. you can pass multiple params to every link based on the behavior you want. If you have existing params you want to include, you can include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, @toddmetheny. I didn't implement your solution, but your solution helped me understand passing multiple parameters a bit more.

I ended up creating a helper, sortable. I also used the url_for to append at the end of whatever the current URL might be. I liked this approach because it meant I could sort on any parameter. I'm not sure that it's the best solution, but it works.

```
def sortable (name, sort)
    link_to name, url_for(params.merge(sort: sort))
end
```